# How do I know when I'm done factoring?

Tags: calculus, limits, factoring

I was attempting to factor

$$\frac{3x^3 + x^2}{x^3 + x^2 + x}$$

I gave up and looked up a solution which was

$$\frac{x(3x + 1)}{x^2 + x + 1}$$

which allowed me to solve for the limit as $x$ approaches $0$, which is $0$. However, at one point when factoring myself I ended up with

$$\frac{3x^2 + 1}{x^2 + x + 1}$$

If THIS were factored enough, the limit would be $1$, but it wasn't. So, I'm just curious how I'm supposed to know that I'm done factoring.

Comment: To be clear, the expression you ended with "*when factoring myself*" was incorrect.  The two terms in the numerator were different by only one power of $x$... compare $3x^3$ to $x^2$.  Your numerator when done should have reflected that, as does the solution you looked up... with the $3x$ compared to $1$ (*remember that $1=x^0$*).  Your attempt looks like it should have been correct if you hadn't made a typo or mistaken pulling an extra term out somehow.

Comment: "*How I'm supposed to know that I'm done factoring*"  Factoring can be hard.  *Really hard* at times.  Thankfully, any example you are given in an academic setting where you are expected to be able to factor should be quite simple in comparison to what you might find out in the wild.  It should be clear if you are done or not from context.  Check for a common factor of $x$ or $x^n$ first as that is easiest to spot (*occurs when missing the constant term*).  Here, $3x^3+x^2$ can have $x$ factored out *twice*, as $3x^3+x^2=x\cdot x\cdot (3x+1)$

Comment: You can use the Euclidean algorithm to find the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) of numerator and denominator.  This is much easier than factoring for polynomials of high degree.
But if you're only worried about limit as $x \to 0$, you only have to check the values at $x=0$.

Comment: Note that the factoring into $x(3x+1)$ isn't really necessary -- if you get $3x^2+x$ (which is the same quantity) in the numerator then you can see that the numerator goes to $0$ as $x\to 0.$ Your mistake was not that you failed to find the last factor of $x$, it is that you took out the first factor of $x$ incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the variables as numbers. The numerator's terms has a common factor of ___ (in your case $x^2$). The denominator's terms has a common factor of ___ (which is $x$). The common factor of $x$ and $x^2$ is $x$. So, pull out an $x$ and cancel to get: $$\frac{3x^2+x}{x^2+x+1}$$The solution you searched up is right since the numerator's terms still have a common factor of $x$. But yours isn't since multiplying by $x$ on the top and bottom gives: $$\frac{3x^3+x}{x^3+x^2+x}\ne\frac{3x^3+x^2}{x^3+x^2+x}$$since the coefficient-less terms in the numerator don't have the same exponent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to take $\lim\limits_{x \to c} \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials, and you can't plug in since $P(c) = 0$ and $Q(c) = 0$, then the polynomials $P$ and $Q$ are divisible by $(x - c)$. Divide both polynomials by $(x-c)$ using polynomial long division and then you can cancel the $(x-c)$ terms. Keep applying this until you don't get $\frac{0}{0}$ when you plug in.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^3 + x^2}{x^3 + x^2 + x}$$
In this case, note that when $x$ goes to $0$, lower powers dominate:
$$\frac{3x^3 + x^2}{x^3 + x^2 + x}\sim\frac{x^2}{x}=x\to 0 $$